# Cron job wget from url that generates an xml on request

Tags: xml, cron, wget

I have a URL that on typing in to the browser will generate a XML file. It takes around 20 seconds to generate as it has 5,000 records. I have had to replace my login details with a * for security.

The cron I am using is:

```
wget -O /home/thefancy/public_html/linn/1.xml -q http://webservices.smiffys.com/services/products.asmx/GetStockQuantities_LightVersion_XML?apiKey=*&clientID=*&filterCode=&filterDescription=
```

This seems to create the 1.xml in the right location. But its a blank file. Why is it doing this?

Comment: Provide the complete cron entry as is. Might be a problem with some other thing if the wget works separately.

Comment: I am using cpanel so this is the whole entry. I have selected the time from the preset options

Comment: 0 0,12 * * * wget -O /home/thefancy/public_html/linn/1.xml -q http://webservices.smiffys.com/services/products.asmx/GetStockQuantities_LightVersion_XML?apiKey=*&clientID=*&filterCode=&filterDescription=

Comment: full cron entry above